# JLabel and Image within JApplet - image isn't show up

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, japplet

On the output label shows up, but image doesn't. It does when I remove the whole label section. I don't know if I have to use clearRect method also.

```
public class Applet1 extends JApplet{

Image img;
JLabel label;

public void init(){

    img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("imagePath"));

    label = new JLabel(getParameter("labelText"));
    label.setFont(new Font(getParameter("labelFont"), Font.PLAIN, Integer.parseInt(getParameter("labelSize"))));

    add(label);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 200, this);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't override the paint() method of a JApplet.

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel. Don't forget to also invoke super.paintComponent(). Then you add the panel to the applet.

Finally you would add the label to the panel.

Also, see [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for the proper way to create the applet. It shows how to use the EDT and a better way to load images.

Comment: I've used your suggestions and it works. I'll post the solution after 8 hours (I've got less than 10 rep). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looking carefully at the original `paint()` override, seems the 3rd paragraph *"..add the label to the panel."* (with an `EmptyBorder`) is all that is needed for this specific use-case - no custom painting whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got something like this, what I've posted below. It works. Thanks.

```
public class Applet1 extends JApplet{

JLabel label;
CustomPanel panel;

public void init(){

    panel = new CustomPanel(getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("imagePath")));

    // ustawianie etykiety
    label = new JLabel(getParameter("labelText"));
    label.setFont(new Font(getParameter("labelFont"), Font.PLAIN, Integer.parseInt(getParameter("labelSize"))));

    panel.add(label);
    panel.setVisible(true);

    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
} 
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel{

Image img;

public CustomPanel(Image img){
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    this.img = img;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 200, this);
}
}
```